# Laravel 5 and Elixir - point to wrong directory

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have a simple script to combine the styles:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        'bootstrap.min.css',
        'font-awesome.css',
        'animate.css',
        'style.css'
    ], "public/frontend/css");
});
```

All my css file are in `public/frontend/css` directory and I set the second argument of the `styles` function to that base but if I run `gulp` I get:

```
[19:18:22] Starting 'default'...
[19:18:22] Starting 'styles'...
[19:18:22] Merging: resources/css/css/bootstrap.min.css,resources/css/public/frontend/css/font-awesome.css,resources/css/public/frontend/css/animate.css,resources/css/public/frontend/css/style.css
[19:18:22] Finished 'default' after 196 ms
[19:18:22] File not found: resources/css/css/bootstrap.min.css
[19:18:22] File not found: resources/css/public/frontend/css/font-awesome.css
[19:18:22] File not found: resources/css/public/frontend/css/animate.css
[19:18:22] File not found: resources/css/public/frontend/css/style.css
[19:18:22] Finished 'styles' after 206 ms
```

So it sets the base directory to `resources/css`.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
I misread the question.

The second argument of `mix.styles()` (and `mix.scripts()`) refers to the output. But it would take a third argument, refering to the base path, so this is the one that you should change, like so:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        'bootstrap.min.css',
        'font-awesome.css',
        'animate.css',
        'style.css'
    ], "path/to/output.css", "public/frontend/css");
});
```

If you want, you can change the base path in the configs, like stated above:

---

Create a `elixir.json` file at the root of your project and then put the following on it:

```
{
    "assetsDir": "public/frontend/"
}
```

And you should be good to go.

Just to provide more information, whenever you need to override a default config, do it in this file.
The default configs are:

```
var config = {
    production: !! util.env.production,
    srcDir: 'app',
    assetsDir: 'resources/assets/',
    cssOutput: 'public/css',
    jsOutput: 'public/js',
    sourcemaps: ! util.env.production,
    bowerDir: 'vendor/bower_components',
    tasks: [],
    watchers: { default: {} },
    duplicate: [],
    concatenate: { css: [], js: [] },
    compile: {}
};
```

from `node_modules/laravel-elixir/Config.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `custom base directory` to the third argument, not to the second.

Combine Stylesheets From A Custom Base Directory ([Ref](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir))

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "normalize.css",
        "main.css"
    ], 'public/build/css/everything.css', 'public/css');
});
```